# I cannot get my text appear as a plain paragraph and it might be due to CSS elements overriding, but I can't find the solution

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage for wishing my friend on her birthday, but I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have a block element with contains her photo (img) and upon hover it scales and then flips to show the back side which I named as "img-back", I want a sweet text on this img-back but it appears in broken lines instead of remaining confined to boundaries of img-back and appear as a nice paragraph. (you will see the paragraph I am talking about in a div classed as img-back and under that there is `<p>` tag)

P.S I am totally new to coding, I just started learning a week or two ago. So bear with me. Thank you :)

```css
  h1 {
  color: yellow;
}

.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s3.amaazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/20140808_StartupStockPhotos/53.jpg');
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  -moz-filter: blur(8px);
  -o-filter: blur(8px);
  -ms-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.x1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #9CB1FF;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

.img1,
.img-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

.img-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #FADA5E;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.x1:hover .img1 {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.x1:hover .img-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.x1 .img1,
.x1 .img-back {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

.x2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 250px;
  color: black;
}

.x3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: #6694FC;
  line-height: 250px;
}

.x4 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 250px;
  background-color: #706AF3;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.x5 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #8593E6;
  line-height: 250px;
}

.block {
  -webkit-animation: scaledown 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: scaledown 1s linear;
  animation: scaledown 1s linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.block:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-animation: scale 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: scale 1s linear;
  animation: scale 1s linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

@keyframes scaledown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

@keyframes enlarge {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.6);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block x1">
        <img class="img1" src="368574575_6780285248674637_7476604192085275316_n.jpg">
        <div class="img-back">
          <p>Kheily shookh tab hastin. Tu yak nemat sheeren hasti, Azizam, Yooram, Joonam, Dostam, Khoshgelam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block x2">I will add image here, and img-back1 with similar effect</div>
      <div class="block x3">I will add image here, and img-back2</div>
      <div class="block x4">I will add image here, and img-back3</div>
      <div class="block x5">I will add image here, and img-back4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried to make this text appear as a nice clean unbroken paragraph which appears on img-back upon hovering, however it appears in broken lines spreading on entire length of screen instead of appear as a nice paragraph on the img-back.

I tried creating jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fdkeaj7r/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `line-height` declaration causes the issue. I've commented it out in the demo snippet.

```css
.x1 {
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```css
  h1 {
  color: yellow;
}

.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://s3.amaazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/20140808_StartupStockPhotos/53.jpg');
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  -moz-filter: blur(8px);
  -o-filter: blur(8px);
  -ms-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.x1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #9CB1FF;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* line-height: 150px; */
}

.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

.img1,
.img-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

.img-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #FADA5E;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.x1:hover .img1 {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.x1:hover .img-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.x1 .img1,
.x1 .img-back {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}

.x2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 250px;
  color: black;
}

.x3 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: #6694FC;
  line-height: 250px;
}

.x4 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 250px;
  background-color: #706AF3;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.x5 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #8593E6;
  line-height: 250px;
}

.block {
  -webkit-animation: scaledown 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: scaledown 1s linear;
  animation: scaledown 1s linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.block:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-animation: scale 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: scale 1s linear;
  animation: scale 1s linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

@keyframes scaledown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

@keyframes enlarge {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.6);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block x1">
        <img class="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150">
        <div class="img-back">
          <p>Kheily shookh tab hastin. Tu yak nemat sheeren hasti, Azizam, Yooram, Joonam, Dostam, Khoshgelam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block x2">I will add image here, and img-back1 with similar effect</div>
      <div class="block x3">I will add image here, and img-back2</div>
      <div class="block x4">I will add image here, and img-back3</div>
      <div class="block x5">I will add image here, and img-back4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```